# capturing data from a txt file through a URL

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a text file on my webserver at, let's say someurl.com/versions.txt. Currently I have my script downloading this file to read the data from it - but I would much rather my script just *read* the data without downloading it, is this possible?

The contents of my txt file would be only `r=#.#`, think of it as version numbers.

Currently, I use powershell to download the file (Which means my command prompt must switch back and forth between powershell), and then a loop to get the data in a variable form.

```
powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest http://someurl.com/versions.txt -OutFile %~dp0versions.txt"  
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%~dp0versions.txt) do set %%G=%%H
```

Is it possible for me to just read that data from the website without downloading the file, thus skipping the step of switching back and fourth between command prompt and powershell? Would this even make a difference in efficiency? I can't find any similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

With [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) you can print the content of the web request to the console:

```
call winhhtpjs.bat https://example.com/text.txt -saveTo con
```

Comment: I would really prefer it to be built into windows, as I'm trying to make it so there are less files needed.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - with this you are not relying on third part binaries ,and you can add what ever you need code in batch part of the script.

Comment: But I would have to have a 2nd bat file?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to use this but I keep getting a 403 error.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)  - do you have access to the server logs? May you need some headers.How the request looks when perfromed through the browser.

Comment: I got it to work by using the command `winhttpjs.bat http://example.com/activator/work.txt -saveTo work.txt -ua \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36\"`